# Cocoa Touch: Why doesn't UINavigationController render 'Back' button?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

When I push a view controller it animates properly and slides in, the only problem is that no 'Back' button is rendered up top.The back button is still there, I can still tap it, it just doesn't render on the screen.

This behavior is identical in both the simulator and on multiple devices.

Is this a known issue or bug? Using 3.1.3 of the iPhone SDK.

More information:
It renders it for further levels, just not on the second level of nav controller.

So Main Page (No back button - OK). Second level page (back button, but doesn't render - not OK). Third level page (Back button there and rendering - OK).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't have a back button if the previous view has no title.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding a second `UINavigationController`? (presumably by accident).  If you have 2 nav controllers they will render the nav bar on top of each other, which could lead to what you are seeing.